# Problems with FireMonkey over VNC and Remote Desktop

Tags: delphi, virtual-machine, effects, firemonkey, vnc

**Settings**: An executable native application written in Delphi FireMonkey (object pascal) application on Windows 64bit and Windows 32bit.  The executable is run from a virtual machine through VNC, typically from an Ubuntu Linux machine to a virtual Windows 7 configuration running the executable.

**Problem**: The problem is when displaying an image (TImage) with effects (TMonochromeEvent, TShadowEffect), the image is not displayed in a VNC connection.  Changing the effect will sometimes render the image, sometimes it will flash for a second and disappear.

The same happens with custom styled TListItem.  They display fine over Windows 7, Windows 8 in 32bit and 64bit when running locally, and work as expected.

Would appreciate ideas and commentary! :-)  Thank you.

Comment: http://delphihaters.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/firemonkey-and-rdp-missing-link.html

Comment: What happens if you compile the app with   GlobalUseHWEffects := False; GlobalUseDirect2D := False; GlobalUseDirect2DSoftware := True; GlobalUseGDIPlusClearType := False; ? Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878064/firemonkey-performance-issues

Comment: Well, it would pretty much ruin the very reason for using FireMonkey.  We want to take advantage of the hardware effects.  I wouldn't mind FireMonkey sensing the situation and reducing the level of effects to network speeds, or even refreshing the display/forms/invalidating every 10-20ms to keep everything visible.  But I don't see a reason for our team to build what I think is a critical component of the FireMonkey engine.  We want to concentrate on the application.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related some settings in VNC (poll full screen?) or the version of VNC you are using (perhaps try UltraVNC or TightVNC).  Are you running VNC as a service?  I believe they have some sort of display driver hook, are you taking advantage of this?  Could you use Remote Desktop Services instead, or LogMeIn?

Comment: Thanks Alister, it happens regardless of VNC mode.  VNC runs as a service.  My problem isn't for myself: we are developing FireMonkey software for customers who may run it over VNC, so switching tools will not be helpful.