# FireMonkey different canvas classes in one application

Tags: delphi, canvas, firemonkey

Is it possible to use different canvas classes in one application (Win\OCX desktop)?

I use `GlobalUseDirect2D = false` to get better text quality (as described in [FireMonkey Performance Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878064/)). But when drawing custom graphics on a `TPaintBox` (or a `TBitmap`) I'd like to use a GPUCanvas to obtain better performance.

Is this possible?